# Create a DAX Table with recursive row calculations

Tags: dax

I want to create a table like

```
VAR startYear = 2000
VAR startAmount = 100
LeasingFee_Datatable =
DATATABLE (
"Year", INTEGER,
"Amount", DOUBLE,
{
// LOOP Until i reach 25 rows or some other condition i like to add later.
{startYear , startAmount },
{ROW0+1, (ROW1+2)100%}
}
)
```

I can't find a way to define a variable for to use inside DAX Table. Any suggestions ?

Comment: DAX does not support recursion. If your goal is to create a table for your data model, it's better to do it in an external application (ie in SQL), and then import the result.

Comment: Thanks RADO. The startYear and startAmount and some calculations i have to use from a measure i created in DAX inside PowerBi reports. Is there any alternate workarounds ?

Comment: Try to explain your objectives in more general terms. Show your data model and the desired outcome, and I'll see what can be done.